# How do I import a sprite sheet with its JSON file into my phaser game?

Tags: javascript, json, phaser-framework, sprite-sheet

I am creating a game using the phaser game engine. I created a sprite sheet and downloaded it. It came with the 256 × 384 .png file with my frames and a JSON file which I assume contains information about how to split up the frames. I don't know how to import the sprite sheet with the JSON file into my preload() function. I tried using the following code but it is not working. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var game = new Phaser.Game(1200, 750, Phaser.AUTO, '', { preload:   preload, create: create, update: update });
function preload(){
    game.load.image('background', 'assets2/background.png');
    game.load.json('robot', 'assets2/VillainSpriteSheet_json.json');
    game.load.spritesheet('robot', 'assets2/VillainSpriteSheet.png');
}

var villain; 

function create(){

var villainjson = game.cache.getJSON('robot');

//enable physics
game.physics.startSystem(Phaser.Physics.ARCADE);

//create background
var background = game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'background');

//villain
villain = game.add.sprite(50, 50, 'robot');

//enable phsyics 
game.physics.arcade.enable(villain);
villain.body.bounce.y = .2;
villain.body.gravity.y = 300; 
villain.body.collideWorldBounds = true;  


}
```

Comment: Did you have a read of the [Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/)

Comment: @haxxxton yes I've tried to read through it. Not much help to me unfortunately because I've never used jQuery before. i was hoping someone could explain it in simpler terms

Comment: where did you create the spritesheet?

Comment: I created it on animated poseur (http://animated-poseur.appspot.com). its an awful module but I was required to use it for this project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are confusing two frameworks, jQuery and Phaser. For loading and displaying sprites you don't need jQuery, just Phaser will do.

The `load.spritesheet` expects a [spritesheet](https://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Loader.html#spritesheet) where all sprites have a **fixed width and height**, so with all sprites in a grid layout.

What you have sounds like a [spriteatlas](https://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Loader.html#atlasJSONHash), the difference being that in a spriteatlas each sprite can have a **different width and height**, and all these widths and heights per sprite are described in the accompanying .JSON file.

So I think you are looking for the `load.atlasJSONHash` function, something like this:

```
function preload(){
    //..
    game.load.atlasJSONHash('robot', 'assets2/VillainSpriteSheet.png', 'assets2/VillainSpriteSheet_json.json');

// and then load a sprite like so
// Note: 'myframename1' should be some framename from the .json file
var villain = game.add.sprite(50, 50, 'robot', 'myframename1');
```

And btw just to clarify, the `load.json` in Phaser can be used to just load a .json file, for example with for your own customised data like level layouts, dialog/multilanguage texts, highscore data, enemy patterns etc.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want jQuery's getJSON(). You want the Phaser one.

It would be something like

```
p = new Phaser.Game(...);
p.cache.getJSON('foo');
p.load.image(...);
```

Comment: Here's a link to the [docs with an example](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/loader/load-json-file)

Comment: thank you. My only problem is that it must also load the .png file. I'm not sure how to load the .png sprite sheet such that it corresponds with he .json file

Comment: Then you will also need the sprite() method to place the image. Let me know if that isn't clear enough and I will provide more into when I'm not trying to do this from my phone :) https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser-examples/blob/master/examples/loader/load%20image.js

Comment: @DanielSmith I edited my question above and put my current code in it. This is what I'm having trouble with

Comment: Hard to read in the comment, but I see 2 things missing. You are going to need a for loop to loop over the loaded json. The first two arguments for the sprite method should be the values of offset X and offset Y I believe.

Comment: @DanielSmith i put the code in the question so it is easier to read. Could you possibly give an example of what your are suggesting?

Comment: Here is another example where JSON is being used. https://github.com/photonstorm/phaser-examples/blob/master/examples/loader/load%20json%20file.js

Comment: what does your example return now?

Comment: No image loads when i load the page in the browser

Comment: are you getting any console errors? specifically 404s related to the image path.

Comment: no. no console errors. Just nothing showing up. Am i using the correct implementation of the json and png files?